# NumberFormatException for inputString: ""

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx, numberformatexception

I'm having a problem with running my JavaFX sudoku app.

I have a method **void updateBoard()** that uses sudokuBoard object and assigns the numbers from textFields to every sudokuBoard field. One textField is responsible for one sudokuBoard field.

```
public void updateBoard() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
                if ((Integer) Integer.parseInt(textFields[i][j].getText()) != null) {
                    sudokuBoard.set(i, j, Integer.parseInt(textFields[i][j].getText()));
                } else {
                    sudokuBoard.set(i, j, null);
                }
                index++;
            }
        }
    }
```

Then I also have a method **boolean checkBoard()** that checks if sudokuBoard is correctly solved.

```
public boolean checkBoard() {
        updateBoard();
        int counter = 0;
        if (difficultyLevel.getLevel() == 0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
                    if (counter % 5 == 0) {
                        if (sudokuBoard.getValue(i, j) == null) {
                            return false;
                        }
                        if (sudokuBoard.getValue(i, j) != difficultyLevel.getRejectedNumbers()[i][j]) {
                            return false;
                        }
                    }
                    counter++;
                }
            }
        }
        if (difficultyLevel.getLevel() == 1) {
            for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
                    if (counter % 3 == 0) {
                        if (sudokuBoard.getValue(i, j) == null) {
                            return false;
                        }
                        if (sudokuBoard.getValue(i, j) != difficultyLevel.getRejectedNumbers()[i][j]) {
                            return false;
                        }
                    }
                    counter++;
                }
            }
        }
        if (difficultyLevel.getLevel() == 2) {
            for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
                    if (counter % 2 == 0) {
                        if (sudokuBoard.getValue(i, j) == null) {
                            return false;
                        }
                        if (sudokuBoard.getValue(i, j) != difficultyLevel.getRejectedNumbers()[i][j]) {
                            return false;
                        }
                    }
                    counter++;
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

when I'm calling method **updateBoard()** from method **checkBoard()** it works perfectly as it should.

Hovewer when I'm calling this method (after pressing the button):

```
public void saveGameSudokuBoardButtonPushed() throws Exception {
    updateBoard();
    Stage stage = (Stage) saveGameSudokuBoardButton.getScene().getWindow();
    FileChooser fileChooser = new FileChooser();
    fileChooser.setTitle("Zapisz plik");
    File file = fileChooser.showSaveDialog(stage);
    FileSudokuBoardDao fileSudokuBoardDao = null;
    try {
        fileSudokuBoardDao = (FileSudokuBoardDao) SudokuBoardDaoFactory.getFileDao(file.toPath().toString()); 
    } catch (NullPointerException exception) {
        exception.printStackTrace();
    }
    
    fileSudokuBoardDao.write(sudokuBoard);
}
```

I get the following error:

```
 Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1787)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1670)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
    at javafx.base/javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8879)
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:200)
    at javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:206)
    at javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.inputmap.InputMap.handle(InputMap.java:274)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.base/javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3851)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1200(Scene.java:3579)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene.processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1849)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2588)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:397)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:295)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$2(GlassViewEventHandler.java:434)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:390)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:433)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:556)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:942)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:174)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at com.sun.javafx.reflect.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:76)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor2.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.reflect.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:273)
    at javafx.fxml/com.sun.javafx.fxml.MethodHelper.invoke(MethodHelper.java:83)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1784)
    ... 47 more
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
    at java.base/java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:68)
    at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:662)
    at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:770)
    at gui.SudokuBoardController.updateBoard(SudokuBoardController.java:86)
    at gui.SudokuBoardController.saveGameSudokuBoardButtonPushed(SudokuBoardController.java:174)
    ... 58 more

Process finished with exit code 0
```

I don't know why the problem occurs while calling **saveGameSudokuBoardButtonPushed()** method and it do not occur while calling **checkBoard()** method.

method **saveGameSudokuBoardButtonPushed()** works perfectly when there is no method **updateBoard()** called inside it.

//EDIT//

I should add that my sudokuBoard has implemented diffuculty levels that remove certain fields from sudokuBoard. Those removed fields are saved in those difficulty level classes and in their places there is null in sudokuBoard field. Then sudokuBoard fields are assigned to textFields on GUI. So it is ok that when I'm trying to save the board that some fields are empty. However I'm wondering why it depends if I'm using updateBoard() method in checkBoard() method and saveGameSudokuBoardButtonPushed() if the implementation is the same for both of them

Comment: The stacktrace is telling you exactly where the exception is being thrown. Place a breakpoint in that line, run in debug mode and start investigating :)

Comment: `udpateBoard` is called at the start of those methods. What is important is what happens before them. For whatever reason `textFields[i][j].getText()` returns empty string when called inside of `saveGameSudokuBoardButtonPushed`. We can't really tell why is that based on the code you provided.

Comment: Somewhere you try to cast "" to a number. "" is not a number so it throws an exception. Stacktrace tells you where this happens. You can put there something like this: if (!str.equals("")) runYourMethod(); - but since you do this, most likely there should be a number and not an empty string so you can just check why is there "" instead of a number.

Comment: Yeah, i should add that my sudokuBoard has implemented diffuculty levels that remove certain fields from sudokuBoard. Those removed fields are saved in those difficulty level classes and in their places there is null in sudokuBoard field. Then sudokuBoard fields are assigned to textFields on GUI. So it is ok that when I'm trying to save the board that some fields are empty. However I'm wondering why it depends if I'm using updateBoard() method in checkBoard() method and saveGameSudokuBoardButtonPushed() if the implementation is the same for both of them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`""` can not be parsed into an integer. Therefore, you need to skip parsing a blank string. You can do it as follows:

```
if (!textFields[i][j].getText().isBlank()) {
    sudokuBoard.set(i, j, Integer.parseInt(textFields[i][j].getText()));
}
```

Comment: I have changed my first if condition in updateBoard() method to what you suggested and it works now :)

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest that you change your code to something like this:

```
String text=textFields[i][j].getText();
text=(text.trim().length()==0?"-1":text);
if ((Integer) Integer.parseInt(text) != -1) {
  sudokuBoard.set(i, j, text));
 } else {
```